# Can't set multiple cookies in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, flask, request

I have two lists:

1. [1, 2, 3]
2. [4, 5, 6]

I iterate over them to generate a cookie like so:

```
for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2):
    url = 'http://www.website.com/{}'.format(i)
    payload = 'encoded{}'.format(j)
    headers = {...}
    request = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response = make_response()
    for key, value in request.cookies.items():
        response.set_cookie(key, value)
return response
```

Only the last cookie is being set, however. I can set cookies for each list by manually indexing into them like so:

```
url = 'http://www.website.com/{}'.format(list_1[1])
payload = 'encoded{}'.format([1])
```

How could I replicate this without hard-coding it so that more than one cookie is set when the return statement is called?

Comment: I've also tried segmenting the function and using threading, but only the first or last cookie would set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the response variable outside your loop. You instantiate it whenever the "for i, j" loop iterates. Like so:

```
response = make_response()
for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2):
    url = 'http://www.website.com/{}'.format(i)
    payload = 'encoded{}'.format(j)
    headers = {...}
    request = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    for key, value in request.cookies.items():
        response.set_cookie(key, value)
return response
```